# Can we Customize the order of selected values for a multi select Component field?

Tags: 2013, content-manager

We have one multi select field in a component, where values are bind with the Category. IT will allow user to select multiple values as check boxes. Once the component got saved the output what we are getting is arranged in alphabetical order. But we are trying to display the selected values in order of their selection. I.e. suppose user have selected these values "bbb", "aaa" & "ccc". 
 Currently result will be as a list and values will be 
 aaa
bbb
ccc. 
 What we are looking for is something like    
bbb
aaa
ccc . 
Which is the order they have been selected.
 Is there any possible way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not out of the box.

One way that springs to mind would be to GUI Extension this baby up. Here's an example (just firing from the hip):

- Give the "select" field a name a prefix of `NoteOrderFIELDNAME`
- Have a "text" field titled `HiddenFIELDNAME`
- In GUI JS detects Hidden prefix in name and hides `HiddenFIELDNAME` via CSS
- In GUI JS detects NoteOrder prefix in name and attaches onClick
- onClick puts value, *retaining selected order* into the `HiddenFIELDNAME`
- Templates refer to value in and parse `HiddenFIELDNAME` rather than the actual category (`NoteOrderFIELDNAME`)

It would be great to then share this GUI Extension as I'm sure it would be useful to others (I'm sure I've been asked about this by a client before).

Comment: Thank you Dylan for this Idea. But we went with the other solution and removed the multi select field and added one component link field where user will link the options as a component.